# Cakephp-2.3 Form Pre filling doesnt load associated data

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have two models in HABT relation.Doctor and Patience.
I'm trying to create an edit form for Patient inside the Doctors controller.When I'm in Doctor controller I want to get all data of the Patients (not related Patients of Doctor )and its related Doctor. I tried the code below but it returns only Patient not its related data.

```
$options = array('recursive' => 2,'conditions' => array('Patience.' .$this->Doctor->Patience->primaryKey => $id));
        $this->request->data = $this->Doctor->Patience->find('first', $options);
```

This only getting Patience model data not its related data.

`Array ( [Patience] => Array ( [username] => akhil [password] => 93477851451f6583c7efd383e715cb6f8accb804 [id] => 4 [name] => akhil [age] => 33 [address] => w4ewrf [cellno] => 324323 [email] => awad@gmail.com [medicines] => sd [diseases] => sdf [misc] => sdf ) [Doctor] => Array ( ) )`

Comment: How did you set up the associations in the models?

Comment: I found the solution.thanks for responding Awemo

Comment: What was the solution?